# Über das Verb "unterstellen"

Tags: word-usage

Ist der folgende Satz möglich?

> Sie unterstellen mir Lügen.

Oder ist eine andere Variante geläufig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dass der Satz möglich ist, hast du selbst bewiesen, indem du ihn formuliert hast. Die Frage ist wohl eher, ob er auch richtig ist, und das ist der Fall.

Eine andere Variante mit derselben Aussage ist

> Sie behaupten, ich würde lügen.

Comment: Meine Frage ist vielmehr, ob du als Muttersprachler den Satz so formulieren würdest.

Comment: Warum stellst du dann nicht genau diese Frage? Die Antwort darauf ist jedenfalls: Ja, Muttersprachler reden wirklich so.

Comment: Ich persönlich hätte eher gesagt: "Sie unterstellen mir, dass ich lüge". "Sie unterstellen mir Lügen" klingt etwas künstlich.